# По маршрутизации в Codeigniter 4

Tags: маршрутизация, codeigniter

Всем доброго дня! Ни разу не работал с Codeigniter, но вот решил попробовать. Поставил все из коробки, убрал index.php из url, больше ничего не трогал. Главная страница открывается по 3 адресам site.loc/ , site.loc/home , и site.loc/Home
Проверил на одном сайте, где точно движок на CI, там конечно проблем с главной нет, по /home получаем 404, но например /categories и /Categories выдает одну и туже страницу.
Вопрос - это же считается дублями или нет? Стоит заморачиваться? И второй момент, как главную сделать так, чтобы она открывалась только по /, без всяких home (ну или любого другого имени класса, который отвечает за главную ) Надеюсь не сумбурно объяснил))
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Регистр в url не важен (обычно) поэтому не дубль.
А главная доступна по нескольким адресам скорее всего из-за настройки

```
$routes->setAutoRoute(true);
```

Выставить false и все маршруты добавлять вручную.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!